# While Loop - Sum of even numbers between two inclusive integers

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, sum, integer

EDIT: Lol I would've never thought you guys would be such savages. I thought this would be the right place for a college student to come and seek for answers. If I didn't care, why would I even be here.. Basically my question is different from the other ones because I do need the first loop to state my even numbers ie: 10  12 14 16 18 20. I sincerely hoped I would get some feedback on how to reinstate the original value of firstNum for the second loop, not criticism expecting to get selected as an answer for points in a matter of seconds.

I've implemented a code that I saw as an answer in a very similar question on the forum. Yet when I compile it, the output for my sum code doesn't return anything. It's just blank. Can I get some feedback on what I am missing or doing wrong? Thank you. *BTW I can only use while loop.*

```
  System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
  int firstNum = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter another integer larger than the first one:");
  int secondNum = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println();

  int mod = firstNum % 2;
  int sum = 0;

  if (mod != 0)
  {
    firstNum++;
  }

  System.out.print("Even numbers: ");
  while (firstNum <= secondNum)
  {
    System.out.print(firstNum + " ");
    firstNum += 2;
  }

  System.out.println();

  System.out.print("Sum of even numbers: ");
  while (firstNum <= secondNum)
  {
    System.out.print(sum);
    sum += firstNum;
    firstNum += 2;
  }
```

Comment: where is your return statement that expect to return some value?

Comment: The result of this code is not just blank.  So:  please state *exactly* what you expected to see, and *exactly* what you see instead.  Also, turn your code into an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the code is running absolutely fine, just confirmed it with my IDE, it is not just blank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output sum of even numbers between two integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313482/output-sum-of-even-numbers-between-two-integers)

Comment: firstNum = 10 secondNum = 20 I would like the sum to be 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop only prints the even numbers, it can not add because the firstNum reaches the secondNum.
If you want to keep the same code you have, you only need to add a new variable that prints even numbers. So the first loop will print the even numbers and the second loop will do the sum.

For example:

```
int evenNumber;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
int firstNum = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter another integer larger than the first one:");
int secondNum = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println();

int mod = firstNum % 2;
int sum = 0;

if (mod != 0) {
    firstNum++;
}

evenNumber = firstNum;
System.out.print("Even numbers: ");
while (evenNumber <= secondNum) {
    System.out.print(evenNumber + " ");
    evenNumber += 2;
}

System.out.println();

System.out.print("Sum of even numbers: ");

while (firstNum <= secondNum) {
    sum += firstNum;
    firstNum += 2;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

This code is not optimal, but it complies with what you need. But if you want to do better, you can do it like this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
int firstNum = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter another integer larger than the first one:");
int secondNum = keyboard.nextInt();
int total = 0;
System.out.print("Even Numbers: ");
while (firstNum <= secondNum) {
    if (firstNum % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(firstNum + " ");
        total += firstNum;
    }
    firstNum++;
}
System.out.println("\nSum: " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

During your first while, you already changed the value of firstNum. So basically, when you arrive to the second while, you don't even enter it.
I would simply change the first loop and delete the second one :

```
while (firstNum <= secondNum) {
        System.out.print(firstNum + " ");
        sum += firstNum;
        firstNum += 2;
    }

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Sum of even numbers: ");
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you, because I need state what the actual even numbers are I would need the first while. But can I rewrite it in another way so I can bring the firstNum to it's initial value while also stating "Even numbers: 10 12 14 16 18 20" ?

Answer (score 0):

In your first while loop -

```
while (firstNum <= secondNum){
    System.out.print(firstNum + " ");
    firstNum += 2;
}
```

you keep incrementing variable `firstNum` until you reach `secondNum`, so the condition of the second while loop (`firstNum <= secondNum`) will never evaluates to true.

A very simple way to achieve your goal can be as follows.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
int firstNum = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter another integer larger than the first one:");
int secondNum = keyboard.nextInt();
int total = 0;
while(firstNum <= secondNum){
    if(firstNum%2 == 0)
        total += firstNum;
    firstNum++;
}
System.out.println("Sum: " + total);
```

Comment: The thing is, this project I can only use while loop, no for loops. I do appreciate your feedback though

Comment: I know, it takes more than 10 seconds to throughly read some information given to me by multiple people and actually implement it into my code to see if it works on my side. I cannot just instantly accept an aswer, I came here to learn.